# simplifying e.target for loop with an if statement

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, checkbox

I have a form with activity checkboxes set up and am working on a POST request where the id's of the checked boxes are being sent as an array of numbers. How would I simplify this for loop?

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let formActivityIds = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.length -1 ; i++ ){
        if (e.target[i].checked ) {
            formActivityIds[e.target.elements[i].getAttribute("value")] = e.target.elements[i].value; 
        }
    }
```

This is currently console logging an array of id's of what is checked but seems like an overly complicated loop. would appreciate any help to simplify it

This is my return statement where I am trying to loop through each e.target[1].value to access the id for items where checked is true.

```
 return ( 
    <div className="check-list">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <ul >
    {orderedActivities.map((activity, index) => {
        return (
            <ul key={index}>
            <input 
            type="checkbox"
            id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
            name={activity.name}
            value={activity.id}
            checked={checkedState[index]}
            onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>  {activity.name}</label>
            </ul>
            
        )
    }
    )}
    <button className='newButton' type="submit">Save Activities</button>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
 );
```

Comment: This for loop condition looks strange: `let i = 0; i < e.target.length -1`

Comment: Can you show some the markup?

Comment: @LizzieAnthony It is not recommended to use the map-index as a key. The key may change on each rerendering. This is supposed to cache some of the nodes so it only needs to update the nodes that have changed. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. You can use the `useId()` from React.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. A little simpler and cleaner and the `parseInt` takes the array of strings to an array of integers.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let formActivityIds = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.length -1; i++) {
        if (e.target[i].checked) formActivityIds.push(parseInt(e.target.elements[i].value))
        // debugger
    }

    // rest of POST request 
}
```

Comment: it is recommended to give `parseInt` a radix (10 in this case).